# Creating a single column from multiple columns (not merging) in SPSS

Tags: join, merge, spss

I have a single data file in SPSS that is organized as such:

| Project (Unique) | Student 1 Name | Student 2 Name | Student 3 Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project A | Barry B. | Roger W. | Frank L. |
| Project B | Rebecca M. | Harry J. | Sam E. |
| Project C | Kit B. | MISSING | MISSING |

I want to create a new table that gives each student their own row (and also lists the project they are affiliated with). Please notice the "MISSING" entries are omitted from the table:

| Project | Student |
| --- | --- |
| Project A | Barry B. |
| Project A | Roger W. |
| Project A | Frank L. |
| Project B | Rebecca M. |
| Project B | Harry J. |
| Project B | Sam E. |
| Project C | Kit B. |

Please help!

I have done quite a bit of googling and watched various YouTube videos on joining, merging, concatenating, and appending. But it seems like I am trying to do something different and I can't pin down what this process is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `varstocases` function to restructure your data from wide to long format. Like this:

```
varstocases /make Student from student1 student2 student3/index=studentN(student).
```

The resulting data structure will be as you described, plus the `studentN` column will have the old student number column labels.